# префикс-функция для алгоритма КМП

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм

Господа, возник вопрос по префикс-функции для алгоритма КМП. Может кто-нибудь подобрать строку, при которой данный ниже код на питоне выведет неправильное значение префикс-функции? В качестве примера привел строку "abcdabcd", которая обрабатывается корректно. Спасибо.

```
def prefix(S):
p=[0]*(len(S)+1)
for i in range(1, len(S)):
    k=p[i-1]
    while k>0 and S[i]!=S[k]:
        k=0 #здесь должно быть k=p[k-1], но подобрать строку надо для k=0
    if S[i]==S[k]:
        k+=1
    p[i]=k
return k

S="abcdabcd"
print(prefix(S))
```

Comment: `print(prefix('000_0000')` ?

Comment: Большое спасибо.